# Append new pythonpath permanently in Geany IDE

Tags: pythonpath, geany

How can I add a new pythonpath in Geany? Is something in the preferences/options that I'm missing? I tried adding this in .bashrc , but it didn't work.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/mypath
```

What I do now is to add these two lines in the top of every script, but it's not good as a permanent solution:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('mypath')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/mypath` to `/etc/profile` and `reboot`.

That should work for you.

Comment: yes it did. thank you. if it's no big deal, please tell me why it worked and it didn't work with bashrc

Comment: .bashrc is a configuration file just for bash,  etc/profile is run when you login. I imagine Geany does not start  bash to run your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it without modifying any system configuration.

In *Geany* go to *Edit > Preferences > Tools*

*Terminal* field should say something like:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "/bin/sh %c"
```

Change it to:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "env PYTHONPATH=/mypath /bin/sh %c"
```